# Генератор не повторяющихся случайных чисел из списка возможных значений

Tags: c++

Здрасьте! Мне нужен генератор не повторяющихся случайных чисел из списка возможных значений, например есть список значений
    int i[] = {1, 123, 2, 3, 4};
Функция или класс должен выбрать какое-либо значение из этого списка, причем оно не должно быть равно одному из предыдущих значений. Я могу сам написать нужный мне класс, но вдруг есть уже готовые решения из других наборов библиотек, дабы мне не изобретать возможный велосипед. В библиотеке boost таких нет

Comment: Если уже есть список готовых значений - то просто перетасуйте его и берите подряд...

Comment: В дополнение - если будет использована только небольшая часть списка, то можно не перемешивать сразу всё, а каждый раз выполнять один шаг тасования Ф-Й.

Comment: Но ведь тасование должно происходить случайно

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: *"Но ведь тасование должно происходить случайно"* `std::shuffle` в помощь.

Comment: ```В библиотеке boost таких нет``` - а с чего им там быть? :) Решение в несколько строк кода навряд ли превратится в один из модулей Boost'а.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i[] = {1, 123, 2, 3, 4};
    size_t size = sizeof(i)/sizeof(i[0]);
    srand(time(0));

    while (size) {
        size_t r = rand() % size;
        std::cout << i[r] << std::endl;
        i[r] = i[--size];
    }
}
```

Comment: `% size` так себе распределение.